# How to find a dense region in 1d

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a set of points in 1d with one region that is much more dense.  Is there a suitable method in scikit-learn (or any other library) to find this dense region? It looks like it should be a clustering problem with the number of clusters set to one but it needs to also be resilient to noise. Or maybe it is an outlier detection problem? Here is a histogram of the sort of data I am talking about.

[image]

I can't upload the real data but here is a simple simulation:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 100

start = 0
points = []
rate = 0.1
for i in range(N):
    points.append(start)
    start = start + random.expovariate(rate)
rate = 10
for i in range(N*10):
    points.append(start)
    start = start + random.expovariate(rate)
rate = 0.1
for i in range(N):
    points.append(start)
    start = start + random.expovariate(rate)
plt.hist(points, bins = 100)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Hist returns the counts and the bins. Maybe you can use that to filter? `n, bins, patches = plt.hist(points, bins=100)`

Comment: For example, look for regions in `n` where the change is greater than some `threshold`: `lims = [bins[i] for i in range(1, len(n)) if abs(n[i] - n[i-1]) > threshold]`

Comment: @pault Wouldn’t I have to set this threshold  as well as the bin size, by hand for every different input data set ? Also I only ever want to find one dense region.

Comment: You could set the bin size as a constant- I guess it depends on the data. As for the threshold, you could infer it from your data. Maybe percentile rank all of the changes and pick something sensible. These are just some ideas- I haven't fully thought through this.

Answer (score 3):

A way to do this without arbitrary choices of discretization, height, etc is to fit a sum of two uniform distributions to the data. The support of one uniform distribution can be fixed: its support is the range of the points, [a, b] below. The other has support [c, d], representing the dense part.

Although scipy.stats has built-in methods for fitting many distributions, I don't see this particular one on the list, so I wrote own `nlf` function which returns the negation of [log likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood_function#Log-likelihood) function. The log likelihood is the sum of logarithms of pdf over the data points. Here the pdf takes only two values, `1/(d-c) + 1/(b-a)` within the dense part, and `1/(b-a)` outside of it. So the computation is based on counting the points within the dense part.

```
from numpy import np
from scipy.optimize import fmin
points = np.array(points)           # should be a numpy array
a, b = points.min(), points.max()
def nlf(params):
    c, d = params
    within = ((points > c) & (points < d)).sum()
    return -np.log(1/(d-c) + 1/(b-a))*within - np.log(1/(b-a))*(len(points) - within)
res = fmin(nlf, (0.9*a + 0.1*b, 0.1*a + 0.9*b), disp=0)
```

The answer (`res`) is `[1046.32119001, 1149.31175184]` (for my instance of your simulated data). Fits well.

The starting point for `c, d` is chosen to be slightly more narrow than `[a, b]` itself to push the optimizer in the right direction. This doesn't force the dense part to be within this interval `(0.9*a + 0.1*b, 0.1*a + 0.9*b)`; the optimizer can expand it if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Kernel Density Estimation**. It will work as a window multiplying your data and smoothing the outliers/noise. Here a pseudo-code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KernelDensity
import numpy as np

#X must be flattend if you use a dataframe (e.g.:
#X = dataframe['x'].values.flatten()
#X = X[:,np.newaxis] )

#apply the kernel and get the probabilities
kde = KernelDensity(kernel='gaussian', bandwidth=1.5).fit(X,sample_weight=y)
probability_density = np.exp(kde.score_samples(X))

#create a density column
dataframe['prob'] = probability_density

#plot
fig = px.line(data,x='x',y='prob')
fig.add_bar(x=data['x'],y=data['y'])
fig.show()
```

You would get something like this:
[image]

The key points here:

- **bandwidth** parameter: the greater the values the smoother the curve is
- to find the **peak**, just take the index of the greatest value in the probability_density, which is the most dense point